# How to extract the "tinfo" IRAF table information

Tags: linux, astronomy, iraf

I want to know how to get the information from a table using **tinfo**. basically I have a table named "coords" and I am running:

```
tinfo("coords")
```

but I dont know how to get the output from this task. For example the number of columns "ncols". From the manual of the **tinfo** task they show the following example:

*"Get size information about the file m87pol.tab, but do not print the information to STDOUT, **just put the values into parameters**"*

```
tinfo m87pol ttout=no
```

What does it means: Put the values into parameters?
How you get the information?

I tried also with the option ttout=yes (display values on terminal) but it shows only the default values and not the real information from the table.

Comment: this is about iraf not astropy, right?

Comment: Astropy is a huge library for astronomy where Pyraf and IRAF are also very much related.

Comment: I know the libraries but pyraf/iraf has nothing to do with astropy.

Comment: Well, that is not the main point of the topic. Please try to contribute to the question itself. Thank you!

Comment: I disagree, it may not be the main point but an important point. I try to figure out if an answer based solely on astropy may be appropriate and there the question text indicates **no** while the tags say **yes**.

Comment: Have you tried something like `tinfo.ncols=` after running `tinfo m87pol ttout=n`?

Comment: Yes! That is working. I am doing print(tinfo.ncols) and works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help!